# Component not rendering when calling this.setState()

Tags: reactjs

I have a component which calling a method in componentDidMount.
This method fetches the data and updates state through `this.setState()`. But then nothing happens. State is updating, but component is not rendering.

There is the code:

```
import React from 'react';
import TimelineChart from './TimeLineChart/index.js';
import axios from 'axios';


class MoneyChart extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            chartData: [{ x: 0, y1: 0, y2: 0 }]
        };
      }
    componentDidMount() {
        this.fillData()
    }

  fillData = () => {
    let prepChart = [{ x: 0, y1: 0, y2: 0 }]
        axios.get('http://0.0.0.0:10003/stream')
        .then(res => {
            res.data.items[0].items.forEach(el => {
                prepChart.push({
                    x: el.date_time,
                    y1: el.total,
                    y2: 0

                })
            });
            this.update_state(prepChart);
        })
}   
    update_state(prepChart) {
        this.setState ({
        chartData: prepChart
        },
        () => console.log(this.state.chartData)
        );
    }


    render () {
        return(<div>
            <TimelineChart height={800} data={this.state.chartData} titleMap={{ y1: 'Этот год', y2: 'Прошлый год' }} />,
        </div>)
    }
}


export default MoneyChart;
```

Here is the TimelineChart code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Chart, Tooltip, Geom, Legend, Axis } from 'bizcharts';
import DataSet from '@antv/data-set';
// import Slider from 'bizcharts-plugin-slider';

import styles from './index.less';

class TimelineChart extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const {
      title,
      height = 400,
      padding = [60, 20, 40, 40],
      titleMap = {
        y1: 'y1',
        y2: 'y2',
      },
      borderWidth = 2,
      data: sourceData,
    } = this.props;

    const data = Array.isArray(sourceData) ? sourceData : [{ x: 0, y1: 0, y2: 0 }];

    data.sort((a, b) => a.x - b.x);

    let max;
    if (data[0] && data[0].y1 && data[0].y2) {
      max = Math.max(
        [...data].sort((a, b) => b.y1 - a.y1)[0].y1,
        [...data].sort((a, b) => b.y2 - a.y2)[0].y2
      );
    }

    const ds = new DataSet({
      state: {
        start: data[0].x,
        end: data[data.length - 1].x,
      },
    });

    const dv = ds.createView();
    dv.source(data)
      .transform({
        type: 'filter',
        callback: obj => {
          const date = obj.x;
          return date <= ds.state.end && date >= ds.state.start;
        },
      })
      .transform({
        type: 'map',
        callback(row) {
          const newRow = { ...row };
          newRow[titleMap.y1] = row.y1;
          newRow[titleMap.y2] = row.y2;
          return newRow;
        },
      })
      .transform({
        type: 'fold',
        fields: [titleMap.y1, titleMap.y2], // 展开字段集
        key: 'key', // key字段
        value: 'value', // value字段
      });

    const timeScale = {
      type: 'time',
      tickInterval: 60 * 60 * 1000,
      mask: 'HH:mm',
      range: [0, 1],
    };

    const cols = {
      x: timeScale,
      value: {
        max,
        min: 0,
      },
    };

    return (
      <div className={styles.timelineChart} style={{ height: height + 30 }}>
        <div>
          {title && <h4>{title}</h4>}
          <Chart height={height} padding={padding} data={dv} scale={cols} forceFit>
            <Axis name="x" />
            <Tooltip />
            <Legend name="key" position="top" />
            <Geom type="line" position="x*value" size={borderWidth} color="key" />
          </Chart>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default TimelineChart;
```

I expect it to re-render after every state change. How can i achieve that?

Comment: Are you getting a response from your `axios` request?

Comment: @Akhilesh yes. And state is updating correctly. All that doesnt work is re-rendering

Comment: You can use the [shouldComponentUpdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate) lifecycle to have more control over your renders

Comment: so what should be inside this method? I mean i already tried a much of variations and nothing has effect

Comment: Compare the `nextState.chartData` with your current state `this.state.chartData` and return true if they are not equal else return false.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But i already tried that. You know, it wasn't a joke when i said i tried  a lot of any possible solutions. I think i tried most of things i found in stackowerflow and google. I also asked in various react and fronted chats.

Well, now i resolved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try binding `update_state` to `this` with [public class fields syntax](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/):

```
update_state = (prepChart) => {
  this.setState({ hartData: prepChart }, () =>
    console.log(this.state.chartData)
  );
};
```

Or just bind it in the constructor:

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {isToggleOn: true};

    // This binding is necessary to make `this` work in the callback
    this.update_state = this.update_state.bind(this);
  }
```

Comment: Can you recreate the issue on [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/vanilla-react-template-irhcq)?

Comment: Im using a third-party components so i think no. But i can try.

Comment: You are asking why component (`MoneyChart`) does not render, it has nothing to do with what you render (`TimelineChart`)

Comment: Maybe you meant to ask why `TimelineChart` does not render? For that you have to show how its implemented

Comment: Should i share TimelineChart?

Comment: I don't know, you tell me

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I found a solution and it's kinda confusing.

Answer (score 0):

```
fillData = () => {
  let prepChart = [{ x: 0, y1: 0, y2: 0 }]
```

Well it was a stupid mistake. Problem was in this second row.

I should change it to `let prepChart = []`. That's all.